# I don't understand 私なのを

Tags: grammar, particles, nominalization

I have this sentence
隣の席が私なのを、感謝しなさい

What does 私なの mean in this case?
Why is there a を with a comma right after?

Answer (score 3):

It's nominalizing.  The sentence means "be thankful that the person in the seat next to you is me."  But more literally, something like "be thankful for the thing/fact/way that, the seat next to you is me."

You could express the same thing as 私であること, but this sounds much more formal.

Comment: To add to this, part of the confusion may be that だ / です becomes な when used with things like (the nominalizer) の, so the statement「隣の席が私だ」("the (person in) the next seat is me") gets turned into a noun by changing the だ to な and tacking on の:「隣の席が私なの」("the fact that the person in the next seat is me"), which then gets used as the object (を) of the larger sentence..